# Digging out email address within xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, selector

Below I am trying to locate the email address within the ReportUser-7-0 Robot strong tag

```
<tr>
<td>
<span class="tablesaw-cell-content report-user">
<strong>ReportUser-7-0 Robot</strong>
<br/>
reportuser-7-0-1494492089@test.xxx.com
<br/>
SubInvestigator-2849  
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

However, the xpath

```
descendant::strong[contains(text(),'ReportUser-7-0 Robot')] and     contains(text(),'reportuser-7-0-1494492089@test.xxx.com')
```

won't find it.

I guess because it doesn't reside in the strong tag - what is the correct way to dig out the email as it doesn't reside in any specific tag. I've tried span but no joy.

Answer (score 2):

Try below `XPath` to get email value `"reportuser-7-0-1494492089@test.xxx.com"`

```
//strong[text()="ReportUser-7-0 Robot"]/following::text()[2]
```

Comment: I would write the tail `/following::text()[contains(., '@')]` to don't depend on amount of <br>  :)

Comment: Yes, it might be useful in case if `HTML` structure could change